# passing multiple arrays as a parameter in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have successfully been able to call a single array as a parameter, but I am having trouble passing through multiple arrays. Here is what I have so far:

```
calling function {
    array1=(1, 2, 3, 4)
    array2=(a, b, c, d)
    array3=(!, @, #, $)

    called function() "${array1[@]" "${array2[@]}" "${array3[@]}"
}

called function {
    local_array1=("${@}")      # i am guessing my problem lies here?
    local_array2=("${@}")      
    local_array3=("${@}")

    echo ${local_array1[@]}
    echo ${local_array2[@]}
    echo ${local_array3[@]}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A function or program's argument list is a single, long array. When you concatenate three different source arrays onto it, the result is still only *one* argument list, with the contents of those three arrays one after the other.

There are two solutions. The safest one is to concatenate onto a single argument list and pass arguments by value, with each array prefixed by its length:

```
caller() {
    array1=(1   2   3   4)
    array2=(a   b   c   d)
    array3=('!' '@' '#' '$')

    callee \
      "${#array1[@]}" "${array1[@]}" \
      "${#array2[@]}" "${array2[@]}" \
      "${#array3[@]}" "${array3[@]}"
}

callee() {
    # using declare -a makes the values truly local
    # without local or declare they're actually global
    declare -a local_array1=( "${@:1:$1}" ); shift "$(( $1 + 1 ))"
    declare -a local_array2=( "${@:1:$1}" ); shift "$(( $1 + 1 ))"
    declare -a local_array3=( "${@:1:$1}" ); shift "$(( $1 + 1 ))"

    printf 'array1 entry: %q\n' "${local_array1[@]}"
    printf 'array2 entry: %q\n' "${local_array2[@]}"
    printf 'array3 entry: %q\n' "${local_array3[@]}"
}
```

---

The other approach is to pass by reference. If you have bash 4.3, you can use a new shell feature called namevars, first implemented by ksh explicitly for this purpose:

```
caller() {
    array1=(1   2   3   4)
    array2=(a   b   c   d)
    array3=('!' '@' '#' '$')

    callee array1 array2 array3
}

callee() {
    declare -n local_array1=$1
    declare -n local_array2=$2
    declare -n local_array3=$3

    printf 'array1 entry: %q\n' "${local_array1[@]}"
    printf 'array2 entry: %q\n' "${local_array2[@]}"
    printf 'array3 entry: %q\n' "${local_array3[@]}"
}
```

However, pass-by-reference is somewhat more fragile: It depends on variable scope being accessible everywhere relevant, and a callee can modify values of the arrays in the caller (indeed, when using the bash-4.3 namevar approach showing here, that behavior is automatic: Any change to `local_array1` will also modify `array1`).

Comment: Interesting what would be an option to pass an array of arrays...

Comment: bash doesn't support arrays of arrays; the closest you could do is an array of names of other arrays, which is what -- in the contest of the code above -- `"$@"` already is. Iterate over them and define them as namerefs and there were are -- basically just replacing the repeated lines in the above with a loop.

Comment: Thank you for helping out! On the first solution for some reason I needed to declare the local variables like so: `declare -a local_array1=( "${@:2:$1}" ); shift "$(( $1 + 1 ))"
    declare -a local_array2=( "${@:2:$1}" ); shift "$(( $1 + 1 ))"
    declare -a local_array3=( "${@:2:$1}" ); shift "$(( $1 + 1 ))"` for it to parse the arrays correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Characters in the third array have special meaning, in bash, two first arrays could be passed & printed like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

called_function()
{
    local local_array1=$1[@]      # i am guessing my problem lies here?
    local local_array2=$2[@] 

    echo ${!local_array1}
    echo ${!local_array2}
}

calling_function() 
{
    array1=(1, 2, 3, 4)
    array2=(a, b, c, d)

    called_function array1 array2 #array3
}

calling_function
```

produced this:

```
./test.sh 
1, 2, 3, 4
a, b, c, d
```

Comment: Pass-by-reference? Definitely clever, but the readers should be aware of the semantic differences between that and the typical pass-by-value approach.